# How to keep a hover effect by selecting a browser suggestion?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, header

I have a WordPress + WooCommerce website and by hovering *Login / Sign Up* on the header it leads to open a dropdown box where you can enter login details or register. The kind of issue described below also occurs on official theme demo website, at https://xstore.8theme.com/

Now, if I click on "Username or email address" field, Google Chrome shows me an account suggestion based on previously saved accounts on this website. You could try by attempting to login with whatever credentials and if you save them on Chrome (even if wrong), the browser will suggest them to you from the next login attempt. If you just hover the suggestion, all the dropdown box disappears. I said, "just hover the suggestion", because actually you do not have time to click on it.

I suppose this is due to hover effect, in fact if you move the cursor out of the dropdown box, this last disappears, and so happens with the suggestion making it like it was out of the dropdown box.

You can watch a video of the issue at:
https://s.nimbusweb.me/share/3721505/q5vwlz9bho2yufufoiic

How could I solve that?

Thank you in advance,
Alberto

Comment: May you include a [mcve] of the issue in the question?

Comment: https://s.nimbusweb.me/share/3721505/q5vwlz9bho2yufufoiic

Comment: Please put the code in the question itself. [Links rot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

Comment: SO provides a "stack snippet" tool to embed runnable code in the question. Creating a minimal reproducable example will help others, and yourself, find a solution quicker. Links rot becuase websites/content goes away.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this Problem many times with outdated versions of chrome.
Have you tried updating your browser?
Do you have the same issue in other browsers?
Running updated chrome, I have not experienced this issue on the Demo Page (https://xstore.8theme.com/)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes, I have both Chrome and Firefox updated at latest version... On Firefox at least, the suggestion remains and I am able to click on it even if the dropdown box disappears as soon as I move curson on the suggestion.

Comment: I assume it to have something to do with the passwdmanager in chrome.
If you clear the PW for that site, do you still get the same error?

Comment: Yes unfortunately I still get the same error... I have no idea how to fix that

Comment: I'm also using the latest Chrome version and also experience this issue where hovering the password manager disables the hover effect of the container and thus hides the dropdown box.